# In Windows 10 Microsoft Edge, how do you scroll page by page?

Tags: windows-10, scrolling, microsoft-edge

When the view is fit to page where I can see an entire page at a time, (i.e. not fit to width), how do I scroll to the next full page at the click of one button?

In Adobe, I would just press page down or left arrow - but this doesn't seem possible in Microsoft Edge which makes reading/scanning incredibly cumbersome.

Answer (score 0):

I was encountering the same problem. I found the solution: click anywhere on the PDF to pop-up the overlay, go to the top right, look for the "Layout Tab, and enable continuous scrolling. This should fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

zoomUp using ctrl+Scroll and you can use pgUp and pgDown